# How can I dynamically use useReducer (or another alternative) in order to prevent writing multiple, repetitive lines of code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, use-reducer

I am writing a program so that a business can display their services, as well as set the prices for each, according to size of item. At the 'Options' component, I am using a useReducer (where I imagine I'll have to create hundreds of 'cases' inside of the useReducer, named after each service). At the 'Service' component, I am using a Formik form to be able to save the values passed to each 'Service'.

This is the 'Options' component, with a userReducer to set prices. Loops over a list of hundreds of services to render hundreds of 'Service' components

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_SMALL_PRICE': //do I have to create hundreds of these with different ids for each?
        return {
          ...state,
          smallPrice: action.payload,
        }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

//really long list that will be looped over
serviceList.map(item => ( 

//do I have to pass hundreds of values here, 
//one for each of the hundreds of 'Service'?
  <Context.Provider value={{ smallPrice, bigPrice }}> 
    <Service
       key={service.id}
       id={service.id}
       name={service.name}
    />)
  <Context.Provider />
```

'Service' component. There will be hundreds of these, and they each need to have prices set separetely (smallPrice, smallPrice2, smallPrice3 ... ?)

```
//In case I would pass down hundreds of items through context 
//in the other component, I thought of passing each an ID 
//and then destructure these conditionally 
//like `smallPrice${props.id}`. Doesn't work unfortunately.               
const { smallPrice } = useContext(Context) 

<Formik
   initialValues={{

//gets this value through Context. also would have 
//to have ids added conditionally (through props, perhaps)
     smallPrice: smallPrice, //smallPrice1, smallPrice2 ?
   }}
   onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {

//e.g SET_SMALL_PRICE_3 perhaps?
       dispatch({ type: 'SET_SMALL_PRICE', payload: values.smallPrice,}) 
            setTimeout(() => {
              setSubmitting(false)
            }, 400)
   }}>
       <Form>

//also change the name here so that it won't affect a different service
         <Field name="smallPrice" type="text" />
       </Form>
<Formik/>
```